# Magento controller action

Tags: debugging, layout, magento, block

Okay, very precisely, I've been tasked with a Magento admin module that doesn't involve layouts, blocks or views. Nothing is ever to be displayed. However, when I call an action in my module's adminhtml controller, Magento keeps trying to render a layout and failing that, redirects to the Dashboard with a "Failed to load source for: http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/modulename/adminhtml_index/actioname" blah, blah, blah.

Now, I've looked at FireBug's Net output for a familiar system action like clearing the cache like so: http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/cache/flushSystem/key/88848f202df8f254b3db13762ad7e949/ and this too responds with "Failed to load source for: http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/cache/flushSystem/key/88848f202df8f254b3db13762ad7e949/"

First of all, this has to be a controller that extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action because otherwise I can't tell if the admin is logged in and has permission to action my controller. Second of all, I don't have a debugging system (and my company's to cheap to spend any money on software engineering) so I have to cave man debug. So my question is, how on earth do debug my code and get output from Magento without loading a layout and rendering blocks? I've tried to output in the predispatch method and exiting before the predispatch ends and this WORKS, but I would prefer not to do any coding in predispatch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: only fool can blame the company being too poor for open-source debuggers like xdebug

Comment: You must know the particulars of my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Firebug says "Failed to load source" it means there is no data to display, typically during a 302 redirect. In a redirection only headers are sent and no body. This matches what you are experiencing.

Secondly your URL contains `admin/modulename/adminhtml_index/actionname` which has four parts. In Magento there should only be three parts like "router/controller/action", which part is extra in yours?

When you have the right action firing don't call `$this->loadLayout()->renderLayout()` because that would, um, load the layout. To output any other content use:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody($content);
```

Comment: So, how do you stop an action from dispatching and preventing the 302 redirect?

Comment: It is redirecting because your URL doesn't exist. Redirecting to the dashboard is how the admin usually handles missing pages.

Comment: Okay, this solved my issue. Have to load and render the layout, which can be removed after debugging. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add only configuration panel then this is done via system.xml and ACL is described via config.xml or adminhtml.xml

your app/etc/modules/Your_Extension.xml would be

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

your app/code/local/Your/Extension/etc/config.xml would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Extension>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Your_Extension>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <extension>
                                            <title>Extension section</title>
                                        </extension>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And app/code/local/Your/Extension/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <extension>
            <label>extension</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>306</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label comment">
                    <comment><![CDATA[short description for one field extension]]></comment>
                    <label>General</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enable_extension>
                            <label>Activate extension</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Activation flag you can access later from code]]></comment>
                        </enable_extension>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </extension>
    </sections>
</config>
```

this is all you need to define a new extension that has one config field in admin side and only three files Your_Extension.xml, config.xml and system.xml are needed.

No controllers needed what so ever and definitely no need for check in a controller if admin is logged in as this is handled by ACL